# Use an object in the same array with coffeescript

Tags: arrays, object, coffeescript

I use Coffeescript in my gulpfile and I would like to use an object declared in the same array but it doesn't work as I can see…

```
# SOURCES
src =
    libs: [
        "#{dir.libs}/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
        "#{dir.libs}/gsap/src/uncompressed/TimelineLite.js"
        "#{dir.libs}/gsap/src/uncompressed/easing/EasePack.js"
        "#{dir.libs}/page.js/page.js"
        "#{dir.libs}/swiper/build/js/swiper.js"
    ]
    js: [
        "#{dir.js}/site.js"
        "#{dir.js}/functions.js"
        "#{dir.js}/animations.js"
        "#{dir.js}/init.js"
    ]
    javascript: src.libs + src.js # this.libs + this.js is the same
```

It's returning `NaN`
Made it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say:

```
javascript: src.libs + src.js
```

your `src` is still `undefined` because you're in the process of building it. You also seem to be under the mistaken assumption that `+` concatenates arrays in (Coffee|Java)Script but it doesn't, `array + array` will stringify the arrays and then concatenate the strings so:

```
[ 'a' ] + [ 'b' ]
```

is actually `'ab'`.

To solve the first problem, build `src` in two steps. To solve the second, use [`Array::concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
src =
    libs: [
        "#{dir.libs}/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
        "#{dir.libs}/gsap/src/uncompressed/TimelineLite.js"
        "#{dir.libs}/gsap/src/uncompressed/easing/EasePack.js"
        "#{dir.libs}/page.js/page.js"
        "#{dir.libs}/swiper/build/js/swiper.js"
    ]
    js: [
        "#{dir.js}/site.js"
        "#{dir.js}/functions.js"
        "#{dir.js}/animations.js"
        "#{dir.js}/init.js"
    ]
src.javascript = src.libs.concat(src.js)
```

Or you could define `libs` and `js` first if that makes more sense:

```
libs = [
    "#{dir.libs}/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
    "#{dir.libs}/gsap/src/uncompressed/TimelineLite.js"
    "#{dir.libs}/gsap/src/uncompressed/easing/EasePack.js"
    "#{dir.libs}/page.js/page.js"
    "#{dir.libs}/swiper/build/js/swiper.js"
]
js = [
    "#{dir.js}/site.js"
    "#{dir.js}/functions.js"
    "#{dir.js}/animations.js"
    "#{dir.js}/init.js"
]
src =
    libs: libs
    js: js
    javascript: libs.concat(js)
```

Comment: Ha! didn't know about that. Prefer the first option for declaring my javascript array. Thank you!